# Unexpected behaviour of SharePoint Regional Settings

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to set date format as MM/dd/YYYY (05/31/2016)for my SharePoint site collection. To do the date format settings I have updated Locale settings from the Site Settings -> **Regional Settings** under **Site Administration**. I have updated Locale as "English (Caribbean)" which sets date format as MM/dd/yyyy (05/31/2016). It works in my development environment. When I have updated same settings on QA server and set Locale as "English (Caribbean)" it shows date format as dd/MM/YYYY (31/05/2016).

I have also tried to get Date using PowerShell with Locale "English (Caribbean)" via Powershell on QA server however it also display date in dd/MM/YYYY format. My client needs date in format of MM/dd/YYYY (05/31/2016).

Is there anyone who face same issue in his career and resolve it. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards,
Jay Doshi

Answer (score 0):

One idea i have is that the personal settings in your profile (mysite) sometimes override the general settings in your web. The same goes for example with languages. Normally SharePoint always looks at the browser for language setting but when it's filled in in your user profile, then it will override the browser language with your selected language. 
This might maybe be something to check out?

Comment: Hi Verthosa,

I have open QA Site and Dev site in same browser. User My site is not created in QA as well as Dev environment. Therefore, I think that might not be an issue.